# git merge from subtree folder in master to branch root

Tags: git, merge, git-subtree

Actually my question is:
**Is there a way to merge from folder in *master* to root in *branch*?**

**What i want is:**

1. read-tree from *branch* to folder in *master* branch
2. make some changes (add files in subtree folder) under *master* branch
3. merge theese changes (added files) from subtree folder in *master* to *branch* root

I've tried this tutorial: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging
But results are unexpected:

I did:

```
    $ git init
    $ touch fileInMaster
    $ git add -A
    $ git commit --all -m 'initial commit'
    $ git checkout master
    $ git remote add rack_remote https://github.com/schacon/rack.git
    $ git fetch rack_remote
    $ git checkout -b rack_branch rack_remote/master
    $ git checkout master
    $ git read-tree --prefix=rack/ -u rack_branch
    $ git add -A
    $ git commit --all -m 'After read-tree to rack folder'
    $ echo 0 > rack/fileInRack
    $ git add -A
    $ git commit --all -m 'Add fileInRack file to rack folder'
    $ git merge --squash -s subtree --no-commit rack_branch
```

What i'm expect is:

- New file 'fileInRack' in *master* branch in *rack* folder
- New file 'fileInRack' in root of *rack_branch*

But after subtree merging git notice me:

> **Deleting rack/fileInRack**
>   Squash commit -- not updating HEAD
>   Automatic merge went well; stopped before committing as requested

But i need adding, not deleting.

So, what am i doing wrong?
Is there other way to merge from folder in *master* to root in *branch*?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
git merge --squash -s subtree --no-commit rack_branch
```

you can do

```
git checkout rack_branch
git merge --squash -s recursive -Xsubtree --allow-unrelated-histories master
git commit -m "commit fileInRack to rack_branch"
```

EDIT: The reason I stumbled across this post is that I have a similar problem, and my solution above doesn't work ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38670331/subtree-merging-master-into-branch-s-recurisve-xsubtree)). Note the edit about the `--no-ff` option. It may be a good idea to always use this option?